# Problems using tikz={xshift=..} in genealogytree

Tags: tikz-pgf, genealogytree

I have cut and paste the example below from the `genealogytree` manual

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}              
\begin{document} 
 \begin{tikzpicture} \genealogytree[template=formal graph, ]{%
  child{
    g{A}   p{B}
    c[tikz={xshift=-20mm,yshift=-5mm}]{C}
    c{D}  c{E}
} }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that it won't compile - I get the error message:

> "I do not know the key '/gtr/tikz', to which you passed 'xshift=-20mm,yshift=-5mm', and I am going to ignore it".

I am clearly missing something, any help appreciated.

Comment: Please put your code in [markdown code block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: Hmmm... it works here.

Comment: @Rmano I have wrong sorry. It works also for me.

Comment: @Sebastiano no problem ;-)!

Comment: @Rmano Just for apologies and fairness.